# use Html.BeginForm at runtime

Tags: javascript, html, html.beginform

i want to use Html.BeginForm conditionally. there are 2 fields inside code as below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Form1Action", "Form1", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{

   <label for="firstlabel">Label 1</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstlabel" name="firstlabel"/>

   <label for="secondlabel">Label 2</label>
      <input type="text" id="secondlabel" name="secondlabel"/>
   <a href="#" class="button" onclick="SubmitForm();">Submit</a>
}
```

and JS is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SubmitForm() {
    $('#form1').submit();
  }
</script>
```

if secondlabel is blank or empty then I want to submit the form by another action, so how can I make this happen?

by another action i mean :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Form2Action", "Form2", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form2" }))
```

Comment: so you have not need to use Html.BeginForm, you only need to change action at runtime by javascript

Comment: why you are putting wrong condition $('#secondlabel').val().length != 0 ---- you want if secondlabel is empty then use form2 action..am i right?

Comment: if you can place your rendered HTML code means (view source in browser)..then would be easy to track your problem..

Comment: i have defined new form as @using(Html.BeginForm("Form2Action", "Form2", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form2" })) {} and applied your logic and its working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
function SubmitForm() {
if($('#secondlabel').val().length)
    $('#form1').submit();
else
 $('#form2').submit();
  }
```

or by changing action

```
    function SubmitForm() {
    if($('#secondlabel').val().length == 0)
        $('#form1').attr('action', $('#form2').attr('action'));


  $('#form1').submit();
      }
```

Comment: So should i define Html.BeginForm("Form2Action", "Form2", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form2" }) ???

Comment: and what will be the form scope? sorry i am new in .net so don't know much

Comment: It depends on you..if you want to change only action dynamically..you can do that also

Comment: Yes i want to change the action at runtime. How can I do this? that is the exact question, which I need to know.

Comment: I modified code for changing action... now it depends on you where you will store this action..so that we can get it in javascript function

Comment: I tried but not working. what should I change in this? $('#form1').attr('action', $('#form2').attr('form2action')); or $('#form1').attr('form1action', $('#form2').attr('form2action'));

Comment: just place my code as it is if you have form2 exist

Comment: I have declared form2 in single line, just above the form1 "using", as Html.BeginForm("Form2Action", "Form2", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form2" }) but its not working.